# Calulating time complexity of loops with in loops example

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

hi I was working with analysis of iterative solution, here is one problem that I am not able to calculate the worst-case running time

```
void function(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for (int j=i; j< i*i; j++)
        {
            if (j%i == 0)
            {
                for (int k=0; k<j; k++)
                    printf("*");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the link to above problem, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithms-set-5-practice-problems/

Please see problem no 7.

What is the time complexity of above function? In the problem, they say it is O(n^5) but I have some doubts about it can somebody provide me some mathematical proof

Comment: If you just want to know "what is the time complexity", the answer is given just below the question at your given link. If you think it's not the correct answer or have doubts about it, say so explicitly.

Comment: In problem they say it is O(n^5) but i have some doubts about it can somebody provide me some mathematical proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your program will crash because `if(j % i == 0)`, both `i` and `j` are 0 
changing your code a bit

```
void function(int n)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<n; i++) // runs O(n) times
        for (int j=i; j< i*i; j++)  
            if (j%i == 0) // runs O(i) times
            {
                for (int k=0; k<j; k++) // runs j times, whenever j is factor of i
                    //that is when j = i, j = 2i ... j = i* i
                    printf("*");
            }
}
```

take an example when `i = 5`

This implies total complexity is

```
for (int j=5; j< 25; j++)  
     if (j%i == 0) // runs O(i) times
     {
      // runs j times when j = 5, 10, 15, 20
            for (int k=0; k<j; k++) {
                printf("*"); // runs j times when j =  5(1 + 2 + 3+ 4)
               // runs  j times which is i*i*(i*(i-1)/2) times
               // runs i^4 times
            }
     }
```

this implies total complexity is O(n^4)

Comment: I also think that it will be Big O of n^4 but I do not understand why they have stated Big O of n^5 because all we need to calculate is no of time the last loop will run in the worst case.

Comment: It is indeed `O(n^4)`, also `O(n^4) is O(n^5)`.

Side note: DO NOT TRUST GEEKSFORGEEKS on anything. Problems over there are not reviewed.

Comment: yeah O(n^4) is O(n^5) but we need to calculate tight asymptotic bound. Okah can you please refer me some source where I can solve some more problem and found reliable answers?

Comment: I don't know of an alternative, but you can see questions with similar tags here. Kindly mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question.

Comment: I still have one doubt combined  complexity of 2nd and third loop is i^4 and I can vary from 1 to n so total will be 1^4+2^4+3^4+4^4......n^4 right? and this will be the running complexity for overall solution Right?

Comment: no combined complexity of inner 2loops is  n^3 because O(i) times O(n^2) see [here](https://ideone.com/fHJ8Y3) for better explanation

Comment: Okh got it ..So actual complexity will be some of first n cubes

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be O(N^5). The first for loop has a range up to n, the second has n^2(considering the highest coefficient term), and the last one is same with the second one. Thus the multiplication of these are n^5.